# POWER BI DAX MEASURE Summation result are not correct

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Hi Power BI User while working on client report i faced a problem where i need to calculate Metric name "Bad_DEBT" . Following Metric calculated based on Logic shared below.

```
VAR monthdiff = DATEDIFF(maxx(portfolio_summary_cutoff_kpi2,portfolio_summary_cutoff_kpi2[Month Year]), TODAY(), MONTH)
VAR newdebtcalc = 
    IF(
        monthdiff > 12,
        [Capital OutstandingM] * 0.95,
        IF(
            monthdiff > 6,
            [Capital OutstandingM] * 0.5,
            MIN([issuedcapitalM] * 0.1, [Capital OutstandingM])
        )
    )
```

Through this expression result look correct for each row But sum does not seem correct . Sum evaluated based on minimum values and show me wrong . Is any way that i can use running total or some logic to display sum in variable and later paste via hastotal function

Thier is no option to generate result calculated column . we have cutt off date which are effecting both KPI issuingcost,capital repiad(other columns) and capital outstanding.

I want correct sum of the column through dax measure

Answer (score 0):

Create a new measure with:

```
Bad_DEBT Total = SUMX(portfolio_summary_cutoff_kpi2, [Bad_DEBT])
```

`SUMX` will evaluate your `[Bad_DEBT]` for each row within `portfolio_summary_cutoff_kpi2` which should hopefully give you the expected results.

Tip: you can replace this line in your `Bad_DEBT` measure:

```
VAR monthdiff = DATEDIFF(maxx(portfolio_summary_cutoff_kpi2,portfolio_summary_cutoff_kpi2[Month Year]), TODAY(), MONTH)
```

With:

```
VAR monthdiff = DATEDIFF(max(portfolio_summary_cutoff_kpi2[Month Year]), TODAY(), MONTH)
```

Comment: Added note: "One-column" aggregators like `MAX` are just syntax sugar for their counterpart iterators (e.g. `MAXX`). This replacement has no bearing on measure *performance*, but readability *is* better for `MAX ( 'Table'[Col] )` vs. `MAXX( 'Table', 'Table'[Col] )`